# a decimal number into 64 bit floating point double precision binary?

Tags: c++, binary

So Ive got a code (from another thread) to convert decimal into floating point binary, problem is its still in 32-bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    union {
        float input;   
        int output;
        }  data;
    float x;
    cin>>x;
    data.input = x;

    bitset<sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT>   bits(data.output); 
    cout << bits << endl;
  }
```

how do i change it into a 64-bit floating point binary?

Comment: what is the decimal number? Do you mean integer? If yes just assign it without any unions. Compiler will add the code to convert the integer value into the float

Comment: What you're doing here is Undefined Behaviour. Unions are not meant to provide a mean of type-punning in C++. Accessing any union member other than last written is UB. And if you want to change `float` to `double`, just use assignment.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Type-punning through unions is not explicitly supported in the C++ standard, but any compiler, now or in the future, that does not do 'the right thing' will break a lot of good, working code out there. Type-punning through unions is very useful, and very widely used.

Comment: @ErikAlapää And invalid according to standard, which means it can format your C: drive with next version of compiler and you cannot complain about that. Of course, it makes no sense for compiler to do anything else that "read these bytes as if they were of this type", but as C++ programmers we are supposed to follow the standard, not do things and hope they would work. `reinterpret_cast` has 2 advantages: it's standard compliant and it's explicitly telling what are you doing (with unions it's much more difficult to tell when you're actually type punning or not)

Comment: I am assuming you just want the binary bits for the float here, not an arbitrary precision decimal type?

Comment: @ErikAlapää Concerning type punning: Of course, it shouldn't be a problem on any future platform to write 8 bytes (of type `uint64_t`) and reading them as other 8 bytes (of type `double`). Doing this with `memcpy()` is not U.B. (AFAIK.) IMHO, the standard simply doesn't allow to read a union member which hasn't been written before. And this might result in: writing a union member doesn't write to memory but keeps the value in a CPU reg. Reading another union member might instead read from memory ignoring that data is not in sync. Arrrg! The C++ compiler is not obligated to recognize this.

Answer (score 0):

**template< std::size_t N >

class bitset;**

This is how bitset Defined in header  file. So if you want 64 bit. Just type 64 inside the bitset. bitset<64> will give you 64 bit output for your desired input.

**Here is the modified code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    union {
        float input;   
        int output;
        }  data;
    float x;
    cin>>x;
    data.input = x;

    bitset<64>   bits(data.output); 
    cout << bits << endl;
}
```

**Input**

```
2.25125
```

**Output:**

```
0000000000000000000000000000000001000000000100000001010001111011
```

**Online compiler link** :
http://cpp.sh/832cr